# Sharepoint web services to edit existing list from desktop

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, moss

Perhaps I am not asking or searching for this correctly:

I want to have a desktop script (currently using python) that will update a list on a sharepoint site.

The current script reads various file shares, ftp sites and a ArcGIS database to determine which metadata files have been updated and published.  The script then writes all these results to a Excel spreadsheet.

We would like to do the same thing, but keep the data in a Share Point list instead of a spreadsheet.  We don't need to upload any files (which is what I keep running across in my search) but just update or add to a list.

We could care less about what language or tools we use, we just don't have access to any custom coding on the Share Point server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the lists webservice on the Sharepoint server,

the url is normally:

```
 http://host/sitename/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```

you are looking at the UpdateListItems webservice call.  I don't know python but I use C# and work with sharepoint every day you can find a working example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/library/ms440289(en-us).aspx) on a Windows app to call the web service.

Comment: So I can just copy Microsoft.SharePoint.dll from the server to the client running that kind of code?  Great.

Comment: You shouldnt need the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll, not sure how python works but in Visual Studio if you add a reference to the webservice you can then use the functions within it.

Comment: Python is just our currently solution, we are agnostic with regards to language.  Thank you for the input!

Comment: You don't need the dll, the web services ASMX page contains the WSDL which tells a calller how to interact with it. Infact the dll is of no use outside of the box that sharepoint is running on.